# Reading event logs saved to XML format from .Net

Tags: c#, xsd, event-log, xmlserializer

I'm trying to read an event log saved as an XML file from .Net / C#, the event log xml format looks (approximately) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Events>
    <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>...</Event>
    <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>...</Event>
</Events>
```

Where the `...` bit is a relatively complex series of types defined in a schema file [event.xsd](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/11/eventdata/events.xsd).

My plan was to use [XSD.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to generate a C# wrapper type for reading this event log XML from this schema file and then deserialise the XML using the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class, like so:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    XmlSerializer serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Events));
    return (Events)serialiser.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

The trouble is that the schema file doesn't contain a definition for the `Events` element (because its not in the schema), and so the above doesn't compile as there is no `Events` type.

I've tried a couple of variations, including using the type `EventType[]` instead of `Events` (which resulted in the exception " was not expected.").  I also attempting to craft my own C# container `Events` type:

```
public class Events
{
    [XmlElement]
    public EventType[] Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

However the above simply results in the `Items` array being null.

How can I read Events Logs saved to XML format from C#?

Comment: Why not just use LINQ to XML and XDocument? Or at worst, XmlDocument?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I just prefer to use XSD generated classes over `XmlDocument` whenever possible, but this will be the technique I fall back on if I can't get this working (I don't like having code scattered with element names hard-coded as strings when I can generate classes from a defined schema instead)

Comment: What hard-coded strings? You mean XPath expressions and element names? BTW, have you tried creating a schema to represent the actual document structure? It would `include` the original schema, but would define the `Events` element.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks - your suggestion helped me figure this out for myself eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed this by using the following class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Events
{
    [XmlElement("Event", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event")]
    public EventType[] Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely certain what it is that made this work where previously it failed (I suspect its the `Namespace` property), however I found this out by using xsd.exe to generate a schema from a saved event log file and and then again to generate C# classes from that file, like so:

```
xsd /c eventlog.xml
xsd /c eventlog.xsd eventlog_app1.xsd
```

(Because it writes two xsd files you need to name both of them on the command line).  I then looked at the resulting C# and compared / experimented until it worked.

Comment: Where does EventType come from?

Comment: @PsychoDad One of these [event types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363662%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)